# what is the diference between javascript scope and angular js scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to learn the difference between JavaScript Scope and Angularjs scope. When I searched online and in SO i found **Scope** in **JavaScript has two scopes: global and local they are mentioning for variable** But in Angular  **$scope is the application object** I am not understanding clearly can somebody help me with some example what is scope..... I want know whether **scope** only the word is same meaning for both the technologies are different kindly explain me

Thanks

Comment: They are entirely different things, but work in a related way. I'm not sure how productive it is to compare the two without confusing the issue further. You need to learn three things: how Javascript scope works, period; how the `$scope` object works in Angular; how Angular templates interact with the `$scope` object.

Comment: i understand from the online scope in javascript is something variable is that correct or my understanding was wrong

Comment: This is extremely well documented in angular docs

Comment: what is wrong in question kindly please explain me why i am getting negative mark

Comment: See [AngularJS - What are Scopes?](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)

Answer (score 4):

**JavaScript**

Scope in JavaScript is the variables to which a particular piece of code has access. It includes the variables in the current function, the variables in any containing functions, and all global variables.

For example here is a simple JavaScript that shows some variables that are and are not in scope for a particular piece of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var a = 1; // in scope

    function W() {
        var b = 2; // not in scope
    }

    function X() {
        var c = 3; // in scope

        function Y() {
            var d = 4; // not in scope
        }

        function Z() {
            var e = 5; // in scope

            // here is my code
            // it has access to a, c, and e
            a = c + e;
        }

    }
</script>
```

The code in function `Z` has access to variables `a`, `c`, and `e`, but not `b` or `d`.

**AngularJS**

AngularJS implements a variation of the [MVC Pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_mvc_architecture.htm). The `$scope` variable is the "model" part of the pattern. The properties that you assign to `$scope` become the variables that are visible to the HTML that uses the scope.

For example, consider this simple example:

```
app.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Hello Cleveland!';
}
```

.

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <span>{{message}}</span>
</div>
```

You assign `$scope.message` in the controller and it is visible as `message` in the HTML.

Scopes in Angular also behave similar to scopes in JavaScript because they inherit from their parents. In Angular, there is the `$rootScope` that all `$scope`s in the application inherit from. Each controller creates a new scope that is a child of the root scope, and child scopes are often created by directives. For example, the `ng-if` directive creates a child scope.

```
app.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Hello Cleveland!';
    $scope.show = true;
}
```

.

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <div ng-if="show">
        <span>{{message}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this example, the `span` is actually in a child scope created by `ng-if`, but it still has access to the `message` property because it inherited it from its parent.

Likewise, you can have sibling scopes that don't interact.

For example, say you have two controllers, "Ctrl1" and "Ctrl2":

```
app.controller('Ctrl1', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'This controller is #1';
}
app.controller('Ctrl2', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'This is the second controller';
}
```

.

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl1">
    <span>{{message}}</span>
</div>
<div ng-controller="Ctrl2">
    <span>{{message}}</span>
</div>
```

The `message` variable is distinct in each one because there is no inheritance relationship between the two.

**Difference**

There is one significant difference between the behavior of scope in JavaScript and in Angular. This behavior is due to the fact that scopes in Angular use [prototypical inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain). There is a lot that has been written about this already, so I won't go into too much detail, but the important thing to remember is this:

> Changing a variable in a child scope does not affect the same-named variable in the parent scope.

Each child scope effectively gets its own copy of all of the inherited properties. When the child scope modifies it, it only modifies its copy, not the parent's.

This is not the case in JavaScript. In the first example, the `Z` function assigns a value to the global `a` variable. This change will be visible to all of the code. The same would not be true in Angular.